# PostgresQL. Select с удалённого сервера ( postgres_fdw)

Tags: postgresql

имеется 2 сервера.
Условно:

- `gr1ser1` - сервер, с которым установлено соединение.
- `gr1ser2` - сервер, присоединённый через create server к серверу 1.
- `gr1ser1_abc` - таблица на локальной машине.
- `gr1ser2_abc` - сторонняя таблица на сторонней машине (`create foregine table`)
- `abc` - таблица с одинаковой архитектурой на двух машинах

Используется `postgres_fdw`

Выполняется запрос:

```
select * from gr1ser1_abc
UNION
select * from gr1ser2_abc
```

Всё красиво, всё работает и выбивает ответ

Но вот разбор фокусов начинается:

Что будет, если сервер `gr1ser2` вдруг отключится. Запрос выполнится с ошибкой (т.е. не выдаст мне ответ), а мне нужно в таком случае получить результат работы `select` из всех работающих серверов (их будет не 2 в конечном итоге).

В итоге вижу только 2 идеи такого обхода:

1. Использовать какие-то обработки конфликтов ( **но для селекта же их нету** ) 
   т.е. что-то типа такого:

   ```
   select * from gr1ser1_abc
   UNION
   select * from gr1ser2_abc on conflict do nothing
   ```
2. использовать функцию, которая проверит все сервера на доступность и выполнит `SELECT` на этих серверах. Но тут я не знаю, как получить список всех работающих серверов.

Можете подсказать, как лучше это решить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы запросили данные из внешней таблицы, но получить эти данные невозможно - запрос необходимо прервать с ошибкой. Это никакой не фокус, а ожидаемое поведение механизма. В отличии от куда более неожиданного получения вовсе неверного результата.

В общем и целом вы хотите неправильную вещь. Выполняйте подключения к нестабильным серверам с приложения, обрабатывайте ошибки на приложении. В том числе вы сильно заблуждаетесь с идеей что вам нужно как-то проверить работает ли сервер. Сервер доступен, вы можете к серверу подключиться, сервер обслуживает запросы, сервер выполнит ваш конкретный запрос - это всё разные состояния. И если вы можете выполнить один запрос - это совершенно не значит, что вы сможете выполнить следующий.

Если вы всё равно очень хотите делать это на стороне postgresql - вам на выбор могу придумать:

- реализовать свой FDW wrapper. Может быть взять за основу `postgres_fdw` `contrib` и добавить обработку параметра типа "вернуть пустое множество при ошибке". Надо смотреть откуда `ereport` идёт
- использовать биндинг к какому-либо языку программирования, сделать хранимку на этом языке и доставать данные по одному серверу. Возможно, даже перехвата [исключений](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) `plpgsql` вместе с [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) окажется достаточно
- сделать `create temporary table` и через `insert into ... select ... from gr1ser2_abc` запросы скопировать данные туда обрабатывая ошибки на приложении инициирующем эти запросы. Затем работать с локальной таблицей

Comment: 1) реализовать свой FDW wrapper. Может быть взять за основу postgres_fdw contrib и добавить обработку параметра типа "вернуть пустое множество при ошибке". Надо смотреть откуда ereport идёт

Кажется очень хорошим вариантом) 
Где можно подробней прочитать про это?

Comment: API: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fdwhandler.html Зеркало исходника `postgres_fdw`: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/postgres_fdw

Answer (score 0):

Если вы всё же хотите продвинуть свой вариант, то вам легче всего создать хранимую процедуру и ловить в ней исключение. Что-то типа:

```sql
BEGIN
  RETURN SELECT * FROM local
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM remote
EXCEPTION WHEN connection_exception THEN
  RETURN SELECT * FROM local;
END
```